# Using C# and Linq to create an array containing unique items from two input arrays

Tags: c#, linq

I have two string arrays containing file names. From those two arrays, I need to produce a third string array that contains only the file names that are unique (i.e., found in one array, but not in both arrays).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var elements = array1.Union(array2).Except(array1.Intersect(array2));
```

Comment: The coders on StackOverflow also never cease to amaze!

Comment: @grant probably because of the Except call. It isn't needed.

Comment: Read the spec, @StraxTillbaka basically wants XOR on an array, `A⊕B == (A AND B) NOT (A OR B), Lee's code does exactly that

Comment: @jdpenix true, I paid too nuch attention to the unique description, not the ie bit :-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `HashSet<T>`. It has an implementation of exactly what you're looking for.

```
var setA = new HashSet<string>(arrayA);  
setA.SymmetricExceptWith(arrayB); // setA is mutated
```

Obviously, you'll need to measure if the cost of initializing a `HashSet` is worth it.